# accessing the return value of a method in java

Tags: java, methods

1. I have a method where I'm trying to get the index of positive list, which satisfies specific condition on modulus of negative list. I'm getting the index of which satisfies, however I also need to access this index in the main method in order to access the positive values only which satisfied that condition.
2. I can't figure out how to access these indexes. I'm lost with the appropriate flow.

   ```
   private static int getIndex(List<Double> positiveList, double nvalues) {

       int index = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < positiveList.size(); i++){

           if(positiveList.get(i)<=nvalues){

               index = positiveList.indexOf(positiveList.get(i));

           }

       }

       return index;

   }
   ```
3. I need to access this index, and get the values of the list in main method..I'm calling the method as

   ```
    getIndex(positiveValues, nvalues);
   ```

   But that's all I know..

Comment: Um, `int index = getIndex(positiveValues, nvalues);`? Basically, use the return value...

Comment: okay..and can I keep it in an array of int index[]..? Because also i need to set those index values as zero later @JonSkeet

Comment: Your method only returns a single index. What array are you talking about?

Comment: Just... no. Filter a list and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get you going, `positiveList.indexOf(positiveList.get(i));` returns `i`, think about what you do here.

What you obviously *want* is a list of arrays that fulfill a certain condition for a given list. Therefore, returning only a single `int index` is not the solution. Try to return a list of all indices, like in this example:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> getIndex(List<Double> positiveList, double nvalues) {
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //something like this
    for(int i = 0; i < positiveList.size(); i++){
        if(positiveList.get(i)<=nvalues){
            indices.append(i); //add an index to the list
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

With this list, you can do whatever you want in your main method now.

Comment: `ArrayList<int>` primitives cannot be used for generics. You need to use `Integer`

Comment: Hey, okay..so I'm storing it like this `ArrayList<Integer> indexValue = getIndex(positiveValues, nvalues);` but with this indexValue how do i access the values present in the positive list which is in the main method? @ZerO

Comment: You iterate over the ArrayList that contains all indices and put every index in your positive list

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = getIndex(positiveValues, nvalues);
```

You create a variable index and stocks the returned value of getIndex in variable index.

Answer (score 0):

`private static int getIndex(List<Double> positiveList, double nvalues)` make it public method so you can access as util method.

```
int index =YourClassNmae.getIndex(positiveValues, nvalues);
```

or inside same class can call directly

```
int index =getIndex(positiveValues, nvalues);
```